# How to rotate a TeeChart 90 degrees

Tags: delphi-2007, teechart

I have an existing component which I have derived from a TeeChart.  It is all tweaked and ready to go.  I now need to display it rotated 90 degrees.  Is this trivial (some property I have not found yet) or complex (start from scratch)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly there are a few options I can think of:

1. If you plan to plot horizontal lines, bars or areas, you should
   consider horizontal series types. There are specific TeeChart series
   styles for that: THorizLine, THorizBar and THorizArea.
2. You can change chart's rotation and elevation properties, for example:

   Chart1.Aspect.Orthogonal:=False;
     Chart1.Walls.Back.Visible:=False;
     Chart1.Aspect.Rotation:=0;
     Chart1.Aspect.Elevation:=300;
3. TChart component is derived from [TCustomPanel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomPanel). You can try to implement the code so a TCustomPanel can rotate as needed.

If you provide more detailed information about your exact needs we might be able to provide a more accurate answer.